# CakePHP 3.6: Object of class Cake\I18n\FrozenTime could not be converted to int

Tags: php, cakephp, time

I am trying to check if a date is later than a week ago in `index.ctp`:

```
(((!isset($task->date_end) || is_null($task->date_end))? 
        strotime('now') : $task->date_end) > strtotime('-1 week'))
```

But I receive this error:

> Object of class Cake\I18n\FrozenTime could not be converted to int

To check if there is anything wrong with the dates in the database I changed them all to : `2019-01-02 05:06:00.000000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compare a non-integer to an integer, PHP's type juggling will try to convert the former to an integer, and `FrozenTime` objects cannot be converted to integers.

You can avoid this fragile construct by using date objects all the way, and use the comparison methods provided by them, for example.

```
$result = true;
if ($task->date_end !== null) {
    $lastWeek = \Cake\I18n\Time::now()->subWeek(1);
    $result = $task->date_end->gt($lastWeek);
}
```

See also

- **[PHP Manual > Language Reference > Types > Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)**
- **[Cookbook > Date & Time](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Chronos](https://book.cakephp.org/chronos/1/en/index.html)**

Comment: Also, by using the `Time` and `Date` objects instead of `strtotime`, you can use `setTestNow` to more easily build reliable unit tests.